# Parsing DateTime in a CSV file in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia, so just wrapping my head around the basics.

I'm trying to read a CSV file into a DataFrame:

```
abc = CSV.File("ABC.csv")
```

The format is as follows:

```
2016-01-04T14:16:00Z,103.71,103.71,103.71,103.71,23300
```

I had expected Julia to recognise the ISO8601 timestamp and parse it to a `DateTime`, but it doesn't seem to have done that. The resulting `typeof` is `String`.

My questions are thus two fold:

- How can I get CSV.jl to parse DateTime on import?
- How can I instantiate a DateTime from a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `Dates` standard library. Suppose you have the following `ABC.csv` file:

```
datetime,x,y,z,w,n
2016-01-04T14:16:00Z,103.71,103.71,103.71,103.71,23300
```

You already know how to read it:

```
julia> using CSV

julia> csv = CSV.File("ABC.csv")
1-element CSV.File{false}:
 CSV.Row: (datetime = "2016-01-04T14:16:00Z", x = 103.71, y = 103.71, z = 103.71, w = 103.71, n = 23300)
```

Notice that you can access a column using:

```
julia> csv.datetime
1-element PooledArrays.PooledVector{String, UInt32, Vector{UInt32}}:
 "2016-01-04T14:16:00Z"
```

This format is not exactly the ISO format supported by default. You can convert it to a date time object using:

```
julia> using Dates

julia> DateTime(csv.datetime[1], "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ")
2016-01-04T14:16:00
```

Now that we know how to convert a single entry of the column, we can use Julia's broadcast syntax to apply to all entries:

```
julia> DateTime.(csv.datetime, "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ")
1-element Vector{DateTime}:
 2016-01-04T14:16:00
```

You can then save the resulting column in a new table. In Julia the CSV.jl table is not the same as the most popular DataFrames.jl table. You can easily convert to it before you start your processing pipeline:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> csv |> DataFrame
1×6 DataFrame
 Row │ datetime              x        y        z        w        n     
     │ String                Float64  Float64  Float64  Float64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 2016-01-04T14:16:00Z   103.71   103.71   103.71   103.71  23300
```

In summary, the following script can be used to convert the data:

```
using DataFrames
using Dates
using CSV

df = CSV.File("ABC.txt") |> DataFrame

df.datetime = DateTime.(df.datetime, "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ")
```

You can find more information in the docstring `?DateTime`.

An alternative solution may exist where you inform CSV.jl of the correct type using the `types` keyword option. Check the docstring `?CSV.File`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `dateformat` option of the `CSV.File` function:

```
julia> DataFrame(CSV.File("file.csv",dateformat="yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ"))
1×6 DataFrame
 Row │ datetime             x        y        z        w        n     
     │ DateTime…            Float64  Float64  Float64  Float64  Int64 
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 2016-01-04T14:16:00   103.71   103.71   103.71   103.71  23300
```